Generate Binary Folder in a p2 Repository Eclipse Plugin for Eclipse RCP
I am new at creating p2 repository in Eclipse RCP et creation of Eclipse Plugin
I need those binary file to compile my program, is someone know how to do it ?
output of my tree command :
── artifacts.jar
├── binary
│   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.executable_root.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.8.1700.v20220509-0833
│   └── org.eclipse.equinox.executable_root.win32.win32.x86_64_3.8.1700.v20220509-0833
├── content.jar
├── features
│   ├── com_1.0.0.11042024134544.jar
│   ├── javax_1.0.0.11042024134544.jar
│   ├── org.apache_1.0.0.11042024134544.jar
│   ├── org.eclipse_1.0.0.11042024134544.jar
│   ├── org.eclipse.core_1.0.0.11042024134544.jar
│   ├── org.eclipse.e4_1.0.0.11042024134544.jar
│   ├── org.eclipse.emf_1.0.0.11042024134544.jar
│   ├── org.eclipse.equinox_1.0.0.11042024134544.jar
│   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.executable_3.8.1700.v20220509-0833.jar
│   ├── org.eclipse.jface_1.0.0.11042024134544.jar
│   ├── org.eclipse.osgi_1.0.0.11042024134544.jar
│   ├── org.eclipse.swt_1.0.0.11042024134544.jar
│   ├── org.osgi_1.0.0.11042024134544.jar
│   └── org.w3c_1.0.0.11042024134544.jar
└── plugins (I don't specify it because i have a many one)



I currently generated the p2 repository with the following command. Even if i have the org.eclipse.equinox.executable_3.8.1700.v20220509-0833.jar, my binary folder and the file it contains are not added in the content and artifacts.jar generated.
It's just generated what i have in the artifacts and features folders.
I expect that my binary folder was contains in my p2 repository
java -jar /home/idefix/cots/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher -metadataRepository file:/share/juno-test -artifactRepository file:/share/juno-test -source /share/juno-test -configs gtk.linux.x86_64,win32.win32.x86_64 -compress -publishArtifacts


This looks like an XY problem. I guess your root problem (Y) is that you are not using Maven/Tycho, which is nowadays the only supported way to build RCP applications. If you build your RCP application with Maven/Tycho, you automatically get these files in binary/.

Ok we have Maven/Tycho in our application the problem (Y) is that our entreprise project is 10 years old and haven't been documented. Right know we are migrating Java 8, eclipe Juno to Java 11 and eclipse 4.24.
I thought our repository were build manually because in our pom p2 repository are just unzip from our maven repo to a work repo p2 and one have those binary/
Thanks to maven-dependency-plugin with an goal unpack, phase generated resources
In fact how do we build a knew p2 repo not manually one ?

The mentioned JAR files in binary are created from the .product file. I recommend setting up a Maven/Tycho build as the first step of the migration: see this tutorial with this example project (or this with an even simpler layout). See also the Plug-in Migration Guide.
